# POSTGRESQL Dollar Quotes in Where Clause

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, dollar-quoting

For people who tried or needed a solution to escape every special character (even $) in a WHERE CLAUSE in POSTGRESQL, here is how it should be use

> the documentation can be somehow hard to understand, and there is no proper example of it so here is mine

e.g : if you want to make a request looking as

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    <TableName> 
WHERE
    <ColumnName> = 'string with ' character';
```

it will throw an error cause "character'" is outside the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is how it should be written:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    <TableName> 
WHERE
    <ColumnName> = $$string with ' character$$;
```

The `WHERE CONDITION` will take the string literally; the interface may look broken but the following instruction will still be interpreted as expected.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    <TableName> 
WHERE
    <ColumnName> = $$string with ' character$$ AND <OtherColumnName> IS NOT NULL;
```

This could even be another escaped string with `$$`.

For details about dollar quoting, look at [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#id-1.5.3.5.9.7.2).